# ASP.NET MVC4 UserProfile

Tags: c#, profile

What is best practice to handle with user profiles in ASP.NET MVC4 ?

I wanna add custom fields to my User Profile like Name, Surname, About and others is it ready solution for this ?

Now my solution is : when creating new user account im creating automaticly a entry in my users table (primary key is user Guid) and there i kepp Name, Surname and point of my oplication  - photos, comments (1 user have many photos, 1 photo have many comments) - is it good solution - or i sit some automaticly magic from MS to do this user profile and link it to my data ?

Answer (score 8):

MVC4 uses a VERY different approach to membership and profiles. The SQL tables are much simpler, but if you reference old tutorials, you'll get very confused very quickly.

It's still quite new, so there isn't a huge amount of reference, but two very useful links for looking into this more are...

http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/30/mvc-4-authentication.aspx

and the first link in the article above
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

In terms of the user profiles, there is now a table holding these (much like the old version) but this time it will have a column per item, not the mess that it used to use before.